# Fitting line with branches to xyz coordinates in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, best-fit-curve

I have a set of points in 3d space which I'd like to fit a line through. The points are pretty tight, but there are obvious branches, as illustrated crudely below. Essentially, I want to describe the "path" implied by this data using one/several equations*

*I should add- it would also work to find a set of coordinates describing the line rather than fitting an equation.

With the black points representing my data (simplified to 2D), the red line is what I'm after

[image: black points representing my data (simplified to 2D), red line is what I'm after]

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how you would go about doing this _not in python_?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.